# Group by ID and get the name by case statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query

```
SELECT ID, TestReason
FROM Test as t
INNER JOIN TestResult as tr ON t.ID = tr.TestID
```

A test can have multiple test results.

The `TestResults` are `A, B, C` or `D, F`.

I need to say for each test, give me the max test result, but the ID's on the test results have nothing to do with the grade, so I have to use the string.

Here are the tables:

**Test**

```
ID    TestReason
int    int
```

**Test Reason**

```
ID    Grade
int   varchar(2)
```

So basically the highest grade trumps all, so if the test (`TestID = 1`) contains a test result of `A,C,C,D,D` I need the 1 record returning like so:

```
1 A
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something but did you try this - since you are using letter grade, then you will use `MIN()`:

```
select MIN(r.grade), t.test_id
from test t
inner join testresult r
  on t.test_id = r.id
group by t.test_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc80e/4)

Or you can use `row_number()`:

```
select grade, test_id
from
(
  select r.grade, t.test_id,
    row_number() over(partition by t.id 
                      order by grade) rn
  from test t
  inner join testresult r
    on t.test_id = r.id
) x
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc80e/8)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
     , TestReason
  FROM Test T
 WHERE TestResult = (SELECT MIN(TestResult) FROM Test WHERE ID = T.ID)
```